# How to change the size of image lager than screen

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, imageview

Im trying **to change an image lager than the screen** so that the image partly(boundary parts) gets out of the screen. The purpose Im doing this is to **make the whole screen filled with the image**. I tried simply changing the height and width bigger than the height and width of screen which I got but it didn't work well. I used code below to get the size of the screen.

```
val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
    val height = displayMetrics.heightPixels
    val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
```

How should I do for this?

Comment: In XML layout set your View height and width with match_parent, your problem will slove.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. Because the image has different ratio with the screen, the image just fill the screen in one direction(horizental or vertical). Im trying to make the screen be totally covered by the image even if some part of image gets out of the screen

Comment: In ImageView you can set the ScaleType attribute to fitXY, Refer to this doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the xml match the height and width of the image to parent and change the `scaleType` attribute to centerCrop -> `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: @josephyumss you can mark this as answered so that others can find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the image to entire screen like a zoomed view, I think you can try image loading libraries like Picasso or Glide to crop the image to fit it inside the layout and also it will handle the caching for large sized images.

For Picasso you can try something like this

```
Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.image).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```